# Mapping to comment out multiple lines with a motion in IdeaVim?

Tags: ideavim

I'm trying to recreate some of https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary function's in IdeaVim.

I've tried various mappings in my `.ideavimrc`, like for example:

```
nnoremap gcc :action CommentByLineComment<CR>
```

Which works fine but I cannot do `2gcc` to comment out two lines. or `ngcc` to comment out `n` lines.

I've also tried to map them like this:

```
nnoremap 2gcc Vj:action CommentByLineComment<CR><Esc>
nnoremap 3gcc V2j:action CommentByLineComment<CR><Esc>
" etc...
```

And like this:

```
nnoremap gc2j V2j:action CommentByLineComment<CR><Esc>
nnoremap gc3c V3j:action CommentByLineComment<CR><Esc>
" etc...
```

But they don't work.

Any help on how this could be accomplished?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Ideavim update 0.52, 2019-07-23](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim/blob/master/CHANGES.md#052-2019-07-23) brought support for [emulation of the vim-commentary plugin](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-1521).
It can be enabled by putting this line to `.ideavimrc`:

```
set commentary
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems IdeaVim contains a number of bugs that prevent the correct execution of this kind of mapping. Feel free to create an issue [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/VIM).

The functionality of commentary extension is on review right now. You can track it's status [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim/pull/109). You can join [Early Access Program](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim#get-an-early-access) to receive updates as fast as it possible.